# Selecting a row where date=NOW()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I am trying to create a table that logs steps depending on date and the user id. But when I run my code, it happens that I get duplicate rows if a user logs their steps several times a day. I can't have a date with a unique key because that would cause all other users unable to log steps if a any other user has logged steps the same day. So my point is that I want to remove the option of having duplicate rows where user id and date is identical. I have two tables

Table a and table b, and I will refer to them as something.a and something.b

I have a problem with returning a valid row when using `$entry = "SELECT * FROM table.a WHERE userid.a = '$user_id.b' AND date=NOW()"`

I want to use it as a conditional to decide to either `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO` table.a. I have `user_id.b` from an previous query which works as it is, so I will leave that as it is for now.

Here is how I query the database:

```
$entry_result = mysqli_query($conn, $entry);
```

Which is used here:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($entry_result) > 0){
    $conn->query("UPDATE steplogger SET steps='$steps' WHERE userid='$user_id' AND date=NOW()");
} else {
    $conn->query("UPDATE users SET totalsteps = totalsteps + ('$steps') WHERE username = '$user'");
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO steplogger (steps, userid, date) VALUES ('$steps', '$user_id', NOW())");
}
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

PS. When I `echo $entry_result` I get a mysqli object.

Comment: If you execute `SELECT NOW()` you'll see it returns something like `2018-10-25 14:42:55`, Are you sure you want `=` with seconds too?

Comment: *The MySQL NOW() function returns the current date and time in the configured time zone as a string or a number in the 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:DD' or 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu' format*

Comment: You could check if `CURDATE()` would be more suitable for you.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I do not know how to answer comments directly, so I guess I'll do it here.

Script47: My database limits itself to only display DD:MM:YY

Alberto: Yes, but my database limits itself to only display and return DD:MM:YY

Dharman: Thanks.

tadman: Wow, haven't really given that a thought. I'll look into that. I actually did an implementation earlier, but didn't really know how to a transaction OOP style. Before you ask about the transaction part, let me just say that I thought I HAD to implement a transaction for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said :

> I want to remove the option of having duplicate rows where user id and date

The best way is to create an UNIQUE index on `user_id` and `date`, this way you won't be able to insert two rows with same `user_id` and `date`.

With an UNIQUE index, you can use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` that will do what you want : you will insert a new row (new `user_id` + `date`) and if a row already exists with the same `user_id` and `date`, you will update the row.

Here is the documentation : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: This resulted in what I feared it would. I suppose I wasn't clear enough in my description of my problem, but the problem is with this type of solution, if a random user has logged some steps on, let's say 27-10-2018, then with a `UNIQUE index` on both `user_id` and `date` other users are not allowed to log steps that same date.

Does this help on understanding my problem?

Comment: So what you say is that you have a generic `user_id` when random user logged in your database? If `user_id` is unique (as it should be), a `UNIQUE index` on `user_id` + `date` will works

Comment: I fixed it by going with a `UNIQUE index` on user_id + date as you said I should. Thanks! I am gonna mark this answer as the correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($entry_result) > 0){
    $conn->query("UPDATE steplogger SET steps='$steps' WHERE userid='$user_id' AND date=".NOW().")";
} else {
    $conn->query("UPDATE users SET totalsteps = totalsteps + ('$steps') WHERE username = '$user'");
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO steplogger (steps, userid, date) VALUES ('$steps', '$user_id', ".NOW()."))";
}
```

To get current date in NOW() function, you can use this [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).
And also format of the two conditions should be same.